# Get name attribute for multiple parents

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have the following code:

```
var parentEls = $(root)
                .find("credit standard")
                .parents()
                .map(function () { 
                  return this.tagName; 
                    })
                .get()
                .join(" > ");
                alert(parentEls);

            $("#breadcrumb").append("<p>" + parentEls + "</p>");
```

This works fine to return the parents. However, I don't want to return tagName, I want the name attribute for each parent instead. I tried

```
.map(function () { 
                      return this.attr("name"); 
                        })
```

but this doesn't work. Is there any way to do this without resorting to a loop?

Comment: Could you please paste your html as well.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm trying to traverse xml:

Comment: <sitemap>
  <products>
    <credit>
    </credit>
  </products>
</sitemap>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411688/how-to-extend-jquery-to-make-it-easier-to-retrieve-the-tagname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr` is no native method, it's a jQuery method. So try to wrap your `this` into a jQuery constructor:

```
return $(this).attr('name');
```

or use the `getAttribute` method instead:

```
return this.getAttribute('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the element with jQuery to use `.attr`. Either use

`this.name`

or `$(this).attr('name')`

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following

```
.map(function () { 
   return $(this).attr("name"); 
 })
```