# enumerate tags by name

Tags: jquery, phpquery

I want to get tag the names from a page using jquery so I can use them as variables.

Example:

```
Tags:
<title>Item Name</title>
<price>$10.00</price>

$tag_name[0] = first tag (this is where jquery code would go)
$tag_name[1] = second tag (this is where jquery code would go)

$item_array[$tag_name[0]][0] = "item name";
$item_array[$tag_name[1]][0] = "$10.00";
```

How can I get the actual name of the tags? I know how to get the contents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can jQuery provide the tag name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532331/can-jquery-provide-the-tag-name)

Comment: How would you identify which tag contained which datum? By position in the document? Within some containing element? etc.

Comment: @Rob Raisch - The tags are all descendants of <item>.

Comment: Your code is not even close to Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`tagName`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/tagName) property to get the tag name.

However, you still need a way to select the tags. If they're contained within an element (eg: `.container`), you could do something like:

```
$(":eq(0)", ".container")[0].tagName // title tag
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/Cfc64/)

Comment: Thanks tagName sent me in the right direction. Probably going to use: string DomElement::tagname ( void )

Comment: @JMC: I could have sworn you asked for a jQuery solution... maybe I'm mistaken ;)

Comment: I did, but then I realized I'm using php not javascript ;). Funny how that works. Most people give me blank stares when I ask questions pertaining to phpquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("*", document.body).click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            alert(this.tagName);
        });
```

Comment: ummmm Why do you need the `$(this).get(0)` why not just use `this`

Comment: my answer is the perfect correct answer to how get the tag name using jquery. Why did I get a negative point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411688/how-to-extend-jquery-to-make-it-easier-to-retrieve-the-tagname

Comment: @XGreen in that example `this` is referring to the jQuery object, here it is referring to the DOM element

Comment: in the jQuery documentation by John Resig the same solution is used. I guess he would know http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: @Xgreen you should quote your sources

Comment: As that would influence how you rate answers?

Comment: @XGreen yes. you should always quote your sources or else thats just stealing someone else's work

Comment: I paste the answer from valid source for the person who asked the question to solve his/her problem. I made sure the answer was taken from a valid source (The library author himself). You claimed you know better by giving negative point but now you don't like it becuase I pasted the link to resigs website showing the same solution

Comment: @XGreen: It does indeed say it in the documentation, however that line is superfluous.  `this` is already the DOM element, so `$(this).get(0)` constructs a jQuery object from the element and then gets the first element from the array, which _is_ the element.  Personally, I'd say a comment to highlight that would be sufficient and that a downvote is harsh, but I'm not the voting police.

Comment: @XGreen you only posted the source **after** it was asked for

Comment: @XGreen see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/how-to-deal-with-questions-or-answers-plagiarising-from-copyrighted-sources

Comment: @Neal: I really don't think taking an example from the API documentation can reasonably be considered "stealing someone else's work".  @XGreen: It's always a good idea to post your sources, because it gives the person reading your answer a chance to see the documentation surrounding it rather than just a code snippet.

Comment: @Town, well i cannot even undownvote. my downvote was not for no source, but for misinformation about `this`

Comment: @Neal: I know, I understand the reason for the downvote. However, the answer _does_ answer the question, it just has a slight overhead in performance, so IMHO I would say that a comment to point that out would be sufficient, giving the answerer the opportunity to amend their answer. It's up to you though, they're your votes! :)

Comment: This website is not for writing university essays. It's for people to get answer to their question so they can get on with their work faster. If what you say was the case people who google forums to find an answer at work should be fired because they get paid for using parts of other people's work.

Comment: @Town with the downvote i can take it away when the user fixes the answer, until then SO does not let me remove the downvote

Comment: @XGreen @Town there is no reason to propogate bad standards though. If your writing `$(this).get(0)` Then your lazy and not thinking, it's simply a low quality answer and those get downvoted.

Comment: @Raynos: Tell that to John Resig ;D

Comment: @XGreen don't worry about it. You've already fixed it. I'm just defending his point. @Town John Resig is doing it wrong ;D, He's not some kind of unquestionable god, he's just a js dev.