# jquery live return false on A tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, live

I have a click bound as live to an element. The handler returns false after execution, but if the element happens to be an A tag, then the link is also not followed, which is unacceptable...

```
$('*').live('click', function(){
  // lots of code here
  return false;
});
```

Now if the element that is clicked on has a path like `A>img` and the image is clicked on, the A will never be followed. I dont want the click event to propagate any further.

how do I achieve this?

Edit:

It is essential for my application to bind the event to *. Also, the clicks can be made on any element, not just A's. Thus none of the mentioned solutions are suitable for what I wish to achieve.

Comment: your code returns false at the end so no action will be performed and you are performing it to all the elements `*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not bind a click function to `*`. You could bind it to the `body` element; the click will propagate from the element that was clicked to the `body` element. You can check the element that was originally clicked like this:

```
$("body").live("click", function (e) {
    if ($(e.originalEvent.target).is("a")) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Having said that, you can still do this:

```
$("*").live("click", function () {
    if ($(this).is("a") == false) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$('*').live('click', function(e){
  // lots of code here
  e.preventDefault();
  return false; // Don't think this is necessary
});
```

I'd also like to say that attaching an event to all elements is probably Not A Good Idea.

You'd be better served by attaching to the `A` tags specifically:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    // lots of code here
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($(this).tagName == 'A')
    return true; // perhaps even { do nothing }
else
    return false;
```

This might not be the exact code to get the tagname, see this [How to extend jQuery to make it easier to retrieve the tagName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411688/how-to-extend-jquery-to-make-it-easier-to-retrieve-the-tagname).

Also see this: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: this.tagName or this.nodeName will suffice

Comment: See the stopPropagation() subsection under "So what do you really want?" in the second link I put up there.  I think it might be what you're looking for, but as Bryan Ross said, you're probably not wanting to attach to every single DOM object.  Thanks for clearing that up, jerjer.